# Next.js: How to show spinner if dynamic CSS files are not loaded?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, user-experience

My Application loads a different CSS file depending on user's role. To do that, I used 'Head' tag from next.js and import it dynamically.

Layout.jsx

```
const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                {
                    role == 'admin' ?
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="admin.css">
                      : <link rel="stylesheet" href="user.css">


                }
            </Head>
        </>
    )
}
```

It works perfect but I don't want to show unsettled or uncolored screen before CSS fully loaded. Is there any way I can get loading state of CSS file so that I can render some spinner or skeleton before it gets loaded.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?